# Root cannot edit crontab

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, cron

I need help. I'm using ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS. i wanna edit the crontab and i already login as root. when i run command "crontab -e", there is already a schedule that download file and execute. i think it's a trojan so i want to remove from crontab but everytime i change the crontab, the error message show "operation not permitted".

[image: crontab list]

[image: cannot edit crontab]

[image: file access]

How to fix this problem and remove the injected script in my crontab?

Comment: How ful are your disks?

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/984818/zuhri) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/984827/zuhri-utama). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 2):

This error message is often shown for files with the 'immutable' or 'append-only' attributes. Use `lsattr` on the files (and their parent folder) to check whether they have this attribute, and `chattr` to remove it.